# Distance between DHCP server and remote pc effect performance?

Tags: performance, dhcp

Hey guys im doing a project where i have to create a WAN network however i was curious whether the distance of the DHCP server will bring down the performance loads if it was held from a different location. I have a branch which contains tills (PCs) and the Head office located 100 miles away where i was planning to hold the DHCP Server, is this a good idea or should i have the DHCP on the router at the branch or would it be best to keep the DHCP server at HO for maintenance aspects. I was told from a friend that it will bring the performance down if held in a far away distance but i was thinking if its only a DHCP server it shouldnt matter too much to the company

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: DHCP server "distance" will not affect network performance (other than taking a bit longer to get a lease). The real questions you need to answer though are 1) what happens when the WAN link goes down? and 2) How will you ensure that DHCP requests (which are dealt with at Layer 2) actually get across your presumably L3 WAN circuit?

Comment: thank you very much for speedy reply and to be honest im not sure how i would tackle those issues, could a possible solution be setting a dhcp server on the router of the branch as well as having a primary dhcp server at the HO?

Comment: @EEAA That's not entirely true... we put a DHCP server on Triton, and it's been nothing but a hassle.  With an 8 hour round trip for packets, it's next to impossible to get a lease from the damned thing.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - You're using the wrong protocol suite. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Internet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The amount of traffic between a client computer and a DHCP server is quite small, so constrained bandwidth between the DHCP server and client isn't really cause for alarm. The nature of the protocol is such that users don't use the DHCP server in an interactive manner, so latency isn't a big deal. From both a bandwidth and latency perspective DHCP is very amenable to working well across a WAN.

DHCP is UDP-based. If your WAN connection is running at close to full utilization DHCP requests may be dropped. Clients and servers will re-send but it would probably be useful to use quality-of-service functionality to guarantee that DHCP has some priority.

Most common routers support a layer-2 to layer-3 encapsulation (often called an "ip helper" or a "DHCP relay agent") to receive, encapsulate, and send DHCP requests over the layer 3 network to your central DHCP server. It's not necessary that this run on your router-- you could have standalone computer in the  branch office fulfilling this function, but it does need to happen. By default, layer 2 broadcasts in the remote office won't be forwarded by a route back to your central DHCP server.

A good argument for putting DHCP in the remote office is to allow IP addresses to be distributed even if the WAN link is down. If, however, the branch office has no connectivity aside from the WAN link and no on-site server resources, then this probably is a moot point. Still, it's worth assessing the impact in scenarios where the WAN has failed and devices are unable to receive DHCP from your central DHCP server.

Edit:

It certainly is possible to place an on-site DHCP server at the branch with "failover" functionality provided by a central DHCP server. The first DHCP server that responds to a client "wins", so in most cases a client will have a lease granted by the on-site DHCP server before a central DHCP server has time to answer.

I don't recommend this kind of ad hoc failover, though. It's not true failover, and likely will perform non-deterministically from time to time. Using DHCP server software that actually supports failover functionality, rather than this "poor man's failover", is a better solution.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, this has been very useful information to me. This is for a project for my final year uni work so i appreciate the help you have provided

Comment: hahaha...Evan got used for homework. ;)

Comment: @TheCleaner - I am not proud. Whatever it takes to get that Legendary badge...